# Getting QueryString from Request or Javascript

Tags: javascript, query-string, asp.net

In aspx I have a querystring - `www.mysite.com/enter.aspx?dest=#`. When I click "enter" I go to `main.aspx`. I want to get this "?dest=#" in `main.aspx` with a `request.querystring` or something in javascript. I need to use the querystring in javascript in main.aspx for another action.

Any ideas?

let me explain in detail -
I have enter.aspx page that shall load with a querystring -
`www.mysite.com/enter.aspx?dest=#`. Now when i click the Enter button on Enter.aspx page, it shall goto Main.aspx page. When main.aspx page loads i want to write small javascript in main.aspx that shall get the querystring from the previous enter.aspx page and give it an if condition.
so if (request.querystring('dest=') > 0
window.open ('a1.jpg')
this above code needs to be redesigned so it can work. how can i do this.
i tried window.location.href.indexof('dest') , nothing happened.

Comment: Please slow down and try to make your question much, much clearer.

Answer (score 3):

```
alert(window.location.search); // ?dest=#
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit messy.. YUI has a simple method to get at the querystring response by Gavin Brock.

[How do you get querystring using YUI 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376517/how-do-you-get-querystring-using-yui-2)

Answer (score 1):

To get the current address in javascript you could use `window.location.href` and test if it contains a given string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.location.href.indexOf('dest=') > 0) {
    window.open('images/newyork.jpg','','') 
}
</script>
```

Comment: its not picking up anything. how does this code know that the previous screen had a querystring? because i am not opening the new window in previous screen. based on querystring i am opening the window in the next screen. dont i need request.querystring?

Comment: window.location.href picks up the current address. You could pass it as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can read the querystring from JavaScript.  Here are some links to get you started:

- http://javascript.about.com/library/blqs1.htm
- http://ilovethecode.com/Javascript/Javascript-Tutorials-How_To-Easy/Get_Query_String_Using_Javascript.shtml
- [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201028080702/http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/04/14/passing-and-retrieving-querystring-using-javascript-in-asp.net.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to do this in Javascript, you can always grab the querystring in the codebehind of enter.aspx, then perform a Response.Redirect to main.aspx, appending on the querystring.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the url from the previous page, you should use "document.referrer".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.referrer.indexOf('dest=') > 0) {
    window.open("a1.jpg");
}
```